# GWT : Draw lines in Tree widget background

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder, gxt

I know there is an option to set an image as tree background and make it to repeat if needed.But i want to draw horizontal lines in the tree background, so that it looks like a table.The horizontal line should fit the entire width of the tree.How can i do this in GWT?.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Add this class to your TreeItem:

```
.gwt-Tree table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.gwt-Tree table td:first-child {
    width: 18px;
}
.myTreeItem {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 39px;
}
.myTreeItem, .myTreeItem > table {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #464646;
}
```

Comment: I want the lines to fit the entire tree width.i.e the line should always start from (0,y).where as now, it starts from the tree item indentation.

Comment: The bottom line starts with indendation for the nested nodes.Can we make it to always start from "X" origin.i.e without indendation ?

Comment: But setting "margin-left" as 0 makes view to look like a table.It doesn't look like a tree.And also, now the bottom border appears only for nodes which have childrens.Bottom border does not appear for leaf nodes.

Comment: I want the nested item to be indended, but not the bottom line.Again, by setting margin-left to 0 makes it to look like table.

Comment: And also the bottom line of the parent node, moves to its last child node, when parent node is expanded.So,this causes, the last leaf node to have 2 bottom lines.

Comment: Hi, i tried adding the styles in UiBinder between Ui:Style tags.But the style is not getting applied.